Showing that a certain kind of measures on C(X) are absolutely continuous with respect to a given measure?
I am trying to complete the proof of the following theorem:
Theorem: Let $B(H)$ be the space of bounded operators on Hilbert space $H$ and let $C(X)$ be the space of continuous functions on a Hausdorff space $X$. Then every positive map $\phi: C(X) \rightarrow B(H)$ is completely positive.
Proof:
Let $\xi_{1}, \ldots, \xi_{n}$ be vectors in $H$. We wish to show
$$
\sum_{i, j=1}^{n}\langle \phi\left(f_{i j}\right) \xi_{j}, \xi_{i}\rangle= \left \langle[\phi\left(f_{i j}\right)]{\left(\begin{array}{c}
\xi_{1} \\
\vdots \\
\xi_{n}
\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}
\xi_{1} \\
\vdots \\
\xi_{n}
\end{array}\right)} \right\rangle \geq 0, 
$$
where $[\phi\left(f_{i j}\right)]$ denotes the n x n matrix with $(i,j)^{\text{th}}$ entry $\phi\left(f_{i j}\right).$
By the Riesz-Markov Theorem there exists a regular Borel positive measure $m$ on $X$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left\langle\phi(f) \xi_{i}, \xi_{i}\right\rangle=\int f d m \quad \text{for all } f \in A.$$
We use the Riesz-Markov theorem again to get regular Borel complex measures $m_{ij}$ on $X$ such that
$$ \left\langle\phi(f) \xi_{j}, \xi_{i}\right\rangle=\int f  d m_{ij} \quad \text { for all } f \in A.
$$
$\dots$
I want to now show that $m_{ij}$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $m$. My approach has been to observe that if $f \in C(X)$ and $f \geq 0$, then we can write $\phi(f) = b^*b$ for some $ b \in B(H)$. Then
$$ \left|\int f  d m_{ij} \right| = \left|\left\langle\phi(f) \xi_{j}, \xi_{i}\right\rangle \right| = \left|\langle b \xi_{j}, b \xi_{i}\rangle\right| 
\leq \|b \xi_{j} \| \| b\xi_{i} \| \leq \sum_{k=1}^n {\|b \xi_{k} \|}^2 = \int f d m. 
$$
It seems to me that this should directly lead to the conclusion that $m_{ij} \ll m$, but I'm unable to proceed from here. Of course, I can use any result on the density of certain classes of measurable functions on $C(X)$, but this approach is not leading me anywhere because I have to approximate via $L^p$ functions with respect to either $m_{ij}$ or $m$, and this choice is preventing me from showing absolute continuity.
Any suggestions are welcome!

If $\psi, \phi$ are two positive linear functionals on $C(X)$ with $\psi \leq \phi$, then the associated Radon measures $\mu_\psi$ and $\mu_\phi$ satisfies $\mu_\psi \ll \mu_\phi$. Indeed, for any open $U \subset X$, by inner regularity on open sets,
$$\mu_\psi(U) = \sup\{\mu_\psi(K): K \subset U \text{ compact}\}$$
By Urysohn’s lemma, there exists a continuous $f: X \to [0, 1]$ s.t. $1_K \leq f \leq 1_U$, so $\mu_\psi(K) \leq \int f \, d\mu_\psi = \psi(f) \leq \mu_\psi(U)$. From this, it is not hard to show that,
$$\mu_\psi(U) = \sup\{\psi(f): 0 \leq f \leq 1_U\} \tag{1}$$
And similarly for $\mu_\phi$ and $\phi$. Hence, as $\psi \leq \phi$, we have $\mu_\psi(U) \leq \mu_\phi(U)$ for all open $U \subset X$. Now, by outer regularity, for any Borel $A \subset X$,
$$\mu_\psi(A) = \inf\{\mu_\psi(U): U \supset A \text{ open}\} \tag{2}$$
And similarly for $\mu_\phi$ and $\phi$. Thus, $\mu_\psi(A) \leq \mu_\phi(A)$ for all Borel $A \subset X$. In particular, $\mu_\psi \ll \mu_\phi$.
Remark: It is worth noting that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are exactly the definition of $\mu_\psi$, if one follows the proof of Riesz representation theorem. So the above is essentially a proof of uniqueness of $\mu_\psi$. Note also that with the way I phrased this, the above proof can easily generalize to the case where $X$ is only locally compact and $C(X)$ is replaced by $C_c(X)$.
Unfortunately, this doesn’t directly solve the issue for $m_{ij}$. Since $m_{ij}$ is a complex measure, $m_{ij} \ll m$ by definition means $|m_{ij}| \ll m$, so what you actually need to prove is, for $f \in C(X)$, $f \geq 0$,
$$\int f \, d|m_{ij}| \leq \int f \, dm$$
(This is strictly stronger than what you wrote down, with the absolute value sign on the outside of the integral.) Since it is hard to explicitly calculate $|m_{ij}|$, here is a workaround: by polarization identity,
$$m_{ij} = \langle \phi(\cdot)\xi_i, \xi_j \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^4 i^k \langle \phi(\cdot)(\xi_i + i^k\xi_j), \xi_i + i^k\xi_j \rangle$$
So $m_{ij}$ is now written as a linear combination of four positive linear functionals. You can just prove each of them is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $m$ using the above. Then $m_{ij} \ll m$ follows.
